# How to use image for background color of linearlayout in android programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]I have a hierarchy of views in which I wanted to set an image with gradient as a linear layout background color.

in swift there were
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: yourImage)
in android how can we do same.

this is gradient image which I want to use
this is my output for my one screen [image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: first i used colorcode for  background color but now I have to use image with gradient for this.so how can I ?   this will be set from global function which will affect to my whole app as you can say it will be used as themecolor. @TruongHieu

Comment: Maybe this is what you need to set `android:background`

Comment: yes but i want image as a color for background

Answer (score 0):

you can use drawable gradient color file as a background like:

gradient_color.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="@color/start_yellow_color"
        android:endColor="@color/end_yellow_color"
       ></gradient>
</shape>
```

and use that in layout

```
Layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_color)
```

Comment: but it doen't give the impact

Comment: @hennapatodiya post your code what you have try, so we can understand easily.